# SSMS 2012 - Refresh Intellisense

Tags: intellisense, ssms-2012

I know that usually when clicking Ctrl+Shift+R will refresh intellisense.
Also, via Edit - Intellisense - Refresh Local cache....

However, I have a script which I run when ever I update my database objects to keep them all in sync.  One part of the script is an update.....

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE MyCol IS NULL)
BEGIN
  UPDATE MyTable 
    SET MyCol = 1
  WHERE MyCol IS NULL;
END
GO
```

Now, previously MyCol was called something else. But now it is called MyCol, I can see it in the Object explorer.
I have the red squiggle under MyCol so I refresh the intellisense cache as per above.  However, no change.
If I copy the update into a new query edit window, no red squiggle.

The update runs OK and I can run the complete script with no issues.  It is just bugging me as to why the squggle won't disapear for this particular script.

I've restarted SSMS, restarted my machine......

What else can I try?

Comment: Also, if I change MyCol to what it was previously named, no red squiggle - but obviously, the statment doesn't run as that column isn't there!

Answer (score 0):

OK - I now realise.
It's because my script creates the table (if not there already) in it's original state and then alters columns etc accordingly.

It seems intellisense it quite clever, but not quite clever enough.

I deduced this by trying the Update statement at the top of the script.
One for the memory bank.